# Semantic Logging permissions error

Tags: windows, service, etw, semantic-logging

I am trying to configure semantic logging on my Windows 8.1 Enterprise environment.

Although I have followed the steps specified by Microsoft [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn774996%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) I get the following error when Semantic Logging service tries to write an Event from ETW.

The  Semantic Logging service is configured Out-of-process.

> ProviderId : d1ed7ec7-5701-5554-2c5e-796dc42511c5 EventId : 803 Keywords : 4 Level : Error Message : A fault was detected while processing the configuration for the element 'ConsoleEventSink'. Message: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the registry key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Winevt\Publishers{a823da5b-1c21-510b-a82d-51508c65c0ca}' is denied. at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.Win32Error(Int32 errorCode, String str) at

Answer (score 0):

Add the identity of the SemanticLogging-svc service instance to the `Performance Log Users` Windows group.